# what's the coherent sheaf and sheaf cohomology on Deligne-Mumford stack ?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks

hello, everyone, I am reading Deligne-Mumford's paper, and the section 4 of this paper, they given some properties of Deligne-Mumford stack without proof. I can't understand the coherent sheaf and sheaf cohomology on Deligne-Mumford stack. Does somebody could explain to me? or show me some reference about sheaf cohomology on Deligne-Mumford stack.

Thank you very much!

Comment: See *Champs Algebriques* by Laumon and Moret-Bailly.